# How to transform permission errors into `null` events on a firebase stream?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I want to emit `null` if there's an error in my stream.

In the simplified example below, the user may not have permission to access the document, in which case `null` is an appropriate stream event for my application.

```dart
Stream<String?> idOrNull() {
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .doc('collection/doc')
    .snapshots()
    // ...if there's an error, I want to emit `null`
    .map((DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snap) {
      return snap.id;
    });
}
```

Reading the [Stream : handleError method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-async/Stream/handleError.html) documentation, there's this less-than-helpful advice:

> If you need to transform an error into a data event, use the more generic Stream.transform to handle the event by writing a data event to the output sink.

Looking into Stream.transform and I'm still non-the-wiser on how to accomplish this task. Advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A StreamTransformer can access the stream sink when handling errors, so this works:

```dart
Stream<String?> idOrNull() {
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .doc('collection/doc')
    .snapshots()
    .transform(
      StreamTransformer<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>,
          String?>.fromHandlers(
        handleData: (snapshot, sink) {
          sink.add(snapshot.id);
        },
        handleError: (error, stackTrace, sink) {
          sink.add(null);
        },
      ),
    );
}
```